# Pressing ESC key through robort class to close the pop up doesn't works in chrome 31 and firefox 26

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, selenium, automation, key

I work on selenium automation, we recently updated our selenium jars to latest selenium version and also updated firefox and chrome to latest,

we have one usecase where on clicking on the ESC key we can close the pop-up.
But the key pressing doesn't works in both the browser.

Answer (score 0):

are u sure clicking ESC button Manually closes POPUP????

if robot class fails try this

```
driver.findElement(By.name("LOCATOR")).sendKeys(Keys.ESC);
```

Robot class is far better than using SendKeys

```
                          (OR)
```

if it is an alert box try  this code you can handle POPUP by using this

```
   try{
            Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
            alert.accept();

    }
    catch(NoAlertPresentException e)
    {
        /****/
    }
```

Hope it helps you

-Ajay